# Как лучше формулировать названия кнопок?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Задумывались над вопросом, как лучше формулировать названия кнопок на сайте? В формате "Что делать?" (к примеру Искать, Изменять, Сохранять) или может лучше в формате "Что я делаю?" (к примеру Ищу, Изменяю, Сохраняю). В последнем случае пользователь как бы общается с сайтом.

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

> или может лучше в формате "Что я делаю?"

Ни в коем случае. Это звучит безграмотно.

> В формате "Что делать?"

Да. Но в совершенной форме глагола: *сохранить, изменить*. Ведь после нажатия на кнопку изменение произойдёт один раз, а никак не несколько. На этом сайте кнопка — "Сохранить изменения".

А вот с третьей командой лучше всего "Поиск" — такой вариант чаще всего на сайтах можно встретить (даже на этом). Если инфинитив, то с зависимыми словами: *Искать по названию*.